# Mysql server from remote computer

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0, firewall

how to expose MySql server that run in a production server (with internet connection) so that I can connect from an external computer of data center to the corporate network?
And how can modify the connection string in my WinForm Application?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Making your database externally available is really an exercise for the DBA, or if that's you a question for https://dba.stackexchange.com/ or perhaps https://serverfault.com/

That being said, your connection string is really the same - you just point to the externally accessible IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. My domain host has a setup that allows to expose that server. All I had to do is "check" that box (stating I like to use external connection for MySQL). Doing so will give me an IP Address (and other connection params) that I can use to make my connection to MySQL. Check your host.

Comment: many thanks for the reply. I will check connectio parameters.